# jQuery Datatables Remove Paging on button click

Tags: jquery, datatables, paging

Is it possible to change the properties of a Data-table defined during initialising based on the actions of user? I do not want to destroy() the table and create or initialise again. Is there some other method? 
I want to remove paging from the datatable, when a user clicks on a button

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "paging": true
} );

<button id="stopPaging"> Stop Paging<button>
```

I want to change to "paging":false on the click of the button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use drow() Api of data  table, follow this url https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call disable and hide the pagination by adding below click event to your js file.

```
$( "#stopPaging" ).click(function() {
  $('#dataTables_paginate').find('a').each(function(e){
        $(this).off('click');
        $(this).parent().css("display","none")
    })
});
```

Hope this will help.

Cheers